# ARM64 Instruction Conversion for DCFS

Tags: arm

As far as I understand, DCSF is a single-precision floating-point literal. I have this instruction, DCFS 0.00001 converting to AC C5 27 37. I am trying to convert DCFS 30 but cannot find any converter that can perform it. Can anyone convert it for me, and preferably, show me how it was done? Thank you!

Comment: It is not clear to me what you are asking. The only mention of DCFS I can find in relation to ARM64 is your question.  How was the 0.00001 value "converted"?  Perhaps you need to specify the value as 30.0 to avoid it being interpreted as an integer.

Comment: I'm simply modifying a game via hex edit. I am trying to change it from DCFS 0.0001 to DCFS 30.0.

Comment: If you were modifying and building the code from source, I'd accept that this was a programming issue and therefore a suitable issue for SO.  As it is that does not appear to be what you are doing, so I think you are on the wrong site for this question. Moreover you really did not try very hard.  I found such a tool just by Googling "convert real number to ieee 754" and found: https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html.  The answer is `00 00 0F 41` (in little-endian order).

Comment: My problem is pretty clear. That had nothing to do with my problem. Thanks anyways.

Comment: and yet you have received no answers - clarity is perhaps best judged by the number of people who understand the question sufficiently to answer it - in this case none.